# How to kill a player near a armor stand in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would like to know how I would be able to kill a player near an armor stand, then kill the armor stand and use the explosion particle at the same time. I'm working on a single command for a claymore and I need it to explode.

I have tried doing this command a couple times but it only killed me when I was near the command block. The command I used is `/kill @p[r=2] [type=ArmorStand,Name=Clamore]` and other versions of this with minor changes.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to put the `/kill` command into a `/execute`:

```
/execute @e[type=ArmorStand,name=Claymore] ~ ~ ~ /kill @a[r=2]
```

Put this into a repeat Command block and next to it place a Chain Command block with this command:

```
/execute @e[type=ArmorStand,name=Claymore] ~ ~ ~ /particle explode ~ ~ ~ <xd> <yd> <zd> <speed> <count>
```

*Example of the `/particle command`: /particle explode ~ ~ ~ 5 5 5 0.1 200 will generate 200 smoke particles around the player within a radius of 5 at a speed of 0.1.*

Next to the 2nd Command block place another Chain Command block with this commmand:

```
/kill @e[type=ArmorStand,name=Claymore]
```

So, altogether this will look like this:

[image: SUPER COMMANDS INSIDE]

Where the left Command block has the 1st command listed above, the middle one the 2nd and the right one has the 3rd.

Answer (score 1):

`/kill` only works with one argument at a time. What this means is that you can only kill one type of entity at once.

In this case, you need to run:

1. `/kill @p[r=2]` first to kill the player, then
2. `/kill @e[type=ArmorStand,Name=Clamore]` to remove the armor stand, then
3. a command to generate the particles (use [this](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#particle) as a reference for the command in question).